# Are there any Minecraft command generators that can make a Sword of the Sun with the same enchantments?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there some possible way to make a Sword of the Sun that will have the same enchantments (sharpness vi, fire protection x, unbreaking vi, flame vi, fire aspect vii, looting i) using command blocks?

Answer (score 1):

```
/give <Player> minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Sword of the Sun"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:20,lvl:10000},{id:21,lvl:10000},{id:34,lvl:10000}]}
```

Copy this in one command block for a diamond sword that is unbreakable has Sharpness V, Fire Aspect, and Looting 10000, and is named 'sword of the sun'.  Now for the effect of fire invulnerability...

Place a command block next to that one and type in or copy and paste...

```
/effect @p fire_resistance 1000000 300 true
```

Link them together with redstone and activate. If this doesn't work then let me know, it would probably be because of the new update some commands work differently now.

Answer (score 0):

Got the command, I even added a lore that says: "The Sword of The Sun....."
Here's The Command

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"\"Sword of the Sun\"",Lore:["\"The Sword of The Sun....\""]},Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:6},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:7},{id:looting,lvl:1},{id:unbreaking,lvl:6},{id:flame,lvl:6},{id:fire_protection,lvl:10}]} 1
```